# Call a Web Api 2 endpoint from a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, json, sql-server-2008, t-sql, asp.net-web-api2

some legacy SQL stored procedure (SQL Server 2008) needs to get some information from a web service (Web Api 2) that I provided.

How to call the endpoint (in GET), retrieve the data (JSON format) and *translate* the data received in a temporary table to be used in the rest of the sproc?

Thanks

Comment: Does my post answer your question? if yes, please consider accepting it. Thanks!

Comment: Here's an example using curl https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2018/04/17/calling-http-endpoints-in-t-sql-using-curl-extension/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way would be to create [Used-defined CLR function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131089(SQL.100).aspx) and call your Web API from there, so you can use full power of C# and .Net libraries to do web calls and parse Json. There is plenty of information on the internet about that. For example: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spike/2010/11/25/how-to-consume-a-web-service-from-within-sql-server-using-sql-clr/. This is not about WebAPI in particular, but you can get the idea from there.

Please note that it would require deployment of your custom assembly with CLR Function(s) to the SQL Server.

**Edit**:

There is a way to do it in TSQL using [OLE Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190501.aspx). See an example [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1904724.aspx?Calling%20a%20Web%20Service%20from%20T%20SQL%20Stored%20Procedure%20using%20MSXML), but it is is much harder, less documented and you will probably spend time inventing you own bicycle instead of using ready solutions from with CLR functions.

Comment: Thanks @jk_xp! Is there nothing built in SQL server to perform an HTTP request?

Comment: Does this answer your question? if yes, please consider accepting it. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can do it easily without writing CLR :

```
Declare @Object as Int;
Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000);

Code Snippet
Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get',
                 'http://www.webservicex.com/stockquote.asmx/GetQuote?symbol=MSFT', --Your Web Service Url (invoked)
                 'false'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT

Select @ResponseText

Exec sp_OADestroy @Object
```

Comment: This is helps me, how i can pass parameters to the service.

Comment: This is fine for calling an XML Web Service, but I believe the original question was how to call a Web API (using JSON, not XML).

Comment: Does this still work for everyone? When I run it, I get the response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">exception</string>

Comment: How to use POST method in this way?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this CLR Stored procedure: [SQL-APIConsumer](https://github.com/geral2/SQL-APIConsumer)

```
 exec  [dbo].[APICaller_POST]
       @URL = 'http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login'
      ,@BodyJson = '{"Username":"gdiaz","Password":"password"}'
```